# Javascript for rounding down in a finance calculator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a finance calculator but I can't get the function correct.

At the moment I have:

```
function calculatepay() {
  var months =  $('#fin_months').val();
  var amount =  $('#fin_amount').val();
  var deposit =  $('#fin_deposit').val();
  var result =  Math.round((amount - deposit) / months).toFixed(2);
  $('#fin_result').val(result);
  $
}
```

It will calculate 1000 / 12 as 83.00 - it should be 83.33.

Can anyone help me figure it out

Comment: Remove `Math.round`

Comment: Use Math.round(num * 100) / 100

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)

Comment: Its an ok question. Why vote it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 2 things:

1. Remove Math.round and only us toFixed if you don't need rounding.
2. Use `Math.round((amount-deposit/months)*100)/100`

So basically, `Math.round((1000/12)*100)/100` will give you 83.33